# Show class probabilities from Numpy array

Tags: numpy, amazon-sagemaker

I've had a look through and I don't think stack has an answer for this, I am fairly new at this though any help is appreciated.

I'm using an AWS Sagemaker endpoint to return a png mask and I'm trying to display the probability as a whole of each class.

So first stab does this:

```
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
pred_map = np.argmax(mask, axis=0)

non_zero_mask = pred_map[pred_map != 0]) # get everything but background

# print(np.bincount(pred_map[pred_map != 0]).argmax()) # Ignore this line as it just shows the most probable

num_classes = 6
plt.imshow(pred_map, vmin=0, vmax=num_classes-1, cmap='jet')
plt.show()
```

As you can see I'm removing the background pixels, now I need to show class 1,2,3,4,5 have X probability based on the number of pixels they occupy - I'm unsure if I'll reinvent the wheel by simply taking the total number of elements from the original mask then looping and counting each pixel/class number etc - are there inbuilt methods for this please?

Update:

So after typing this out had a little think and reworded some of searches and came across this.

```
    unique_elements, counts_elements = np.unique(pred_map[pred_map != 0], return_counts=True)
    print(np.asarray((unique_elements, counts_elements)))
#[[    2     3]
#[87430  2131]]
```

So then I'd just calculate the % based on this or is there a better way? For example I'd do

```
87430 / 89561(total number of pixels in the mask) * 100
```

Giving 2 in this case a 97% probability.

Update for Joe's comment below:

```
rec = Record()
recordio = mx.recordio.MXRecordIO(results_file, 'r')
protobuf = rec.ParseFromString(recordio.read())
values = list(rec.features["target"].float32_tensor.values)
shape = list(rec.features["shape"].int32_tensor.values)
shape = np.squeeze(shape)
mask = np.reshape(np.array(values), shape)
mask = np.squeeze(mask, axis=0)
```

Comment: Is class in your case some RGB range? 1: 0-60, 2:61...120 etc?

Comment: Hey Joe so that map is generated from the updated code above.

Comment: So actually the pred_map is simply [[0,0,0,1.,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]] or whatever the actually class number is.

Comment: You already mentioned np.bincount above, that should work. also np.histogram might be an option. Maybe I am not understanding the task or it is really that simple :) https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html#numpy.histogram

Comment: You want to colorize objects in an image right? And you want to color the regions with a linear color scale showing how big (in pixels) they are?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was to use `np.digitize` and write a nice solution.

But then I realized how you can hack it in 10 lines:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

size = (10, 10)

x = np.random.randint(0, 7, size) # your classes, seven excluded.

# empty array, filled with mask and number of occurrences.
x_filled = np.zeros_like(x)

for i in range(1, 7):

    mask = x == i
    count_mask = np.count_nonzero(mask)

    x_filled[mask] = count_mask

print(x_filled)    

plt.imshow(x_filled)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

I am not sure about the axis convention with imshow
at the moment, you might have to flip the y axis so up is up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SageMaker does not provide in-built methods for this.